# MySQL query most recent records from one table but in the order from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

really new to mysql. I'm trying to query from table2 to show the most recent logins from each users but I wanted to show the result in order of uid in table1. I'm using this query that I found from another thread but it shows the result base on timestamp and not by uid:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS x
GROUP BY username
```

here are the tables and the result I'm looking for:

table1

```
------------------
| uid | username |
------------------
|  1  | user1    |
------------------
|  2  | user2    |
------------------
|  3  | user3    |
------------------
|  4  | user4    |
------------------
```

table2

```
--------------------------------------------
|     timestamp        | username | logins |
--------------------------------------------
| 2014-02-18 23:29:31  | user2    | OUT    |
--------------------------------------------
| 2014-02-18 23:28:31  | user2    | IN     |
--------------------------------------------
| 2014-02-18 23:27:31  | user3    | OUT    |
--------------------------------------------
| 2014-02-18 23:26:31  | user1    | IN     |
--------------------------------------------
| 2014-02-18 23:25:31  | user2    | OUT    |
--------------------------------------------
| 2014-02-18 23:24:31  | user3    | IN     |
--------------------------------------------
```

I'm looking to get a result like this

```
--------------------------------------------
|  username |      timestamp      | logins |
--------------------------------------------
|  user1    | 2014-02-18 23:26:31 | IN     |
--------------------------------------------
|  user2    | 2014-02-18 23:29:31 | OUT    |
--------------------------------------------
|  user3    | 2014-02-18 23:27:31 | OUT    |
--------------------------------------------
|  user4    | null                | null   |
--------------------------------------------
```

I hope this is clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `table2.username`, `table2.timestamps`, `table2.logins`
FROM `table2`
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) AS ts, `username`
  FROM `table2`
  GROUP BY `username`
) AS `t`
ON `t.username` = `table2.username` AND `t.ts` = `table2.timestamp`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `table1`
ON `table1.username` = `table2.username`
ORDER BY `table1.uid`
```

First I have a joined `table2` with a derived table `t`. This derived table gets the latest timestamp per user. You cannot get the correct value of `login` column if you dont use this derived table. Next I have done a `RIGHT JOIN` with `table1` to get `uid` so it can used in the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: this works too but it's not showing the exact result I was looking for but that's my fault base on my question/tables. This query only shows users who have _logins_ events in table2. I edited my tables to reflect the exact result I was looking for. I apologize for that and thanks for your help.

Comment: @egglog In that case, an `OUTER JOIN` will be required. I have updated my answer above, please check.

Comment: It was showing _null_ on some of the rows under the _username_ column. On the first line I changed _table2.username_ to _table1.username_ and works perfectly. Thanks again for your help.